# How to add value in array of object with the same name and same date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have an array of object i want to add the total based on the date and the name. so if the date and the name is equal we will add the total in the object.  for example i have this list of object

```
[{name: A, total: 3,date: 01-01-20,},{name: A,total: 4,date: 01-01-20,},{name: A,total: 7,date: 02-01-20,},]
```

i want to achieve something like this

```
  [{name: A,total: 7,date: 01-01-20,},{name: A,total: 7,date: 02-01-20,},]
```

Comment: How the date will equal the name? I don't understand...

Comment: example if name and date is equal to another object in the list it will add the total {name: A, total: 3,date: 01-01-20} with {name: A, total: 5,date: 01-01-20,} same name and date so it will merge to {name: A, total: 8,date: 01-01-20,}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{name: 'A', total: 3,date: '01-01-20'},{name: 'A',total: 4,date: '01-01-20'},{name: 'A',total: 7,date: '02-01-20'}];

arr = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {  
  let find = obj.find(i => i.name === item.name && i.date === item.date);  
  let _d = {  
    ...item
  }
  find ? (find.total += item.total ) : obj.push(_d);
  return obj;
}, [])

console.log(arr);
```